# Group list by UserId and get fastest TimeSpan

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, timespan

I have a class let's call it `Tasks`. Then a `List<Tasks>` that contains a bunch of `tasks`. Many users can have many `tasks` into this list.

```
public class Tasks
{
    public string UserId { get, set }

    public DateTime StartDate { get, set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get the fastest time to complete a `task` per `UserId`. Basically if `UserId = 123` has 5 tasks, I want only the fastest one and so forth for all users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
    var list = yourPopulatedListOfTasks;
    var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.UserId).Select(x=> new{
        UserId = x.Key,
        MaxTimeSpan = x.Min(y=>y.EndDate-y.StartDate)
    });
```

**May be off topic but:**
Your naming is not quite good. It should be in singular as your `Tasks` class actually represents a single task. And i would not use `Task` as a name for my class because it the name of a well-know class in .net, and this might cause confusions.

Comment: You missed the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var result = lst.GroupBy(c => c.UserId, (key, element) => new
{
    key,
    fast = element.Min(d => d.EndDate - d.StartDate)
});
```